# How do Konoha's powers work?

Tags: kami-sen

In Kami Sen, Konoha is a god of poverty (though she denies this). She seems to have a number of special powers, but it's hard to tell exactly how they work. In some cases, she seems to be deliberately controlling them, while other times it seems to be subconscious. It's also implied that having more followers makes her more powerful, as does being in love. In some cases her powers seem to actually help the main characters while in others she brings misfortune.

How, exactly, do her powers work? What determines how powerful they are, and whether she can control them?